Parallelizing over huge for loop involving a generator
Is there a way to compute in parallel the maximum value of an array so big I need to use a generator in parallel? I am computing the maximum value of a function over a very large discrete set of matrices (9 billion elements) but the sequential code takes around 200 hours to run on Google colab's CPU.
Going into more detail, I have a 680x4 array and need to compute a function taking in four rows of the array, not allowing duplicate rows and where order doesn't matter. From these rows I create a 4x4 matrix and evaluate my function. This gives 680 choose 4 ~ 9 billion possible matrices. I am currently using a generator that returns each possible combination, creating the matrix, applying my function, and keeping track of the maximum value. I imagine there must be a nice way of parallelizing so that I can run it on GPU.
Here's a summary of for loop code. The rows are given.
max_value = 0

for combination in tqdm(combinations_generator, total = total_iterations):
    A = rows[torch.tensor(combination)] # Create matrix with chosen rows
    value_A = function(A) # compute function of the matrix

    if value_A > max_value: # keep track of maximum value
        value_A, best_A = value_A, A


It would be nice to know function: it is key to know if it is vectorizable - but also, if some analytic work can be done so that combinations with certain patterns can be filtered out and skipped without being computed (this might give you an orders-of-magnitude fold in getting your result)

The function is the average value of the maximum coordinate in absolute value (the infinity norm) of Ax where x ranges over all binary vectors with coordinates (-1, 1)^4, of which there are 16.  In code, function(A) = torch.mean(torch.max(torch.abs(A @ binary_vectors), dim=0).values) where binary_vectors is the 4 x 16 matrix containing all of these binary vectors in columns. In practice I have taken only the first 8 columns of binary_vectors since the infinity norm is invariant under the map x -> -x

You search for best (in some way) 4-length subset of matrix rows/columns. Its my guess that its possible to do better algorithm than brute-force. Cound not understand what you wrote in that comment though.

You can use create a pool of workers and use starmap(), which maps a function to an iterable of argument tuples.
import numpy as np
import torch
from itertools import combinations, islice
from tqdm import tqdm
import multiprocessing as mp


def function(matrix):
    return torch.sum(matrix)


def _run(combination, rows):
    A = rows[torch.tensor(combination)]
    value_A = function(A)
    return value_A, A


def _chunked(gen, size):
    igen = iter(gen)
    for first in igen:
        chunk = [first] + list(islice(igen, size - 1))
        if chunk:
            yield chunk


def _parallel_workers(rows, wks=4, chunks=10000):
    gen = combinations(range(len(rows)), 4)
    counts = len(rows) * (len(rows) - 1) * (len(rows) - 2) * (len(rows) - 3) // 24

    max_value, best_A = 0, None
    with mp.Pool(wks) as pool:
        for chunk in tqdm(_chunked(gen, chunks), total=(counts // chunks) + 1):
            vals = pool.starmap(_run, [(comb, rows) for comb in chunk])
            for value_A, A in vals:
                if value_A > max_value:
                    max_value, best_A = value_A, A

    return max_value, best_A


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(_parallel_workers(torch.rand(680, 4), wks=mp.cpu_count()))





I hope you are aware in this code, the expression  [(comb, rows) for comb in tqdm(gen, total=counts)]) will generate all 9 billion matrices eagerly in memory, in the root process, right? That'd be worth mentioning.

@jsbueno You're right. My bad... we need to break it into chunks...
